# How to find out what script a CMD.exe process is running on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a server which has several mission critical scripts that run in CMD.exe windows as a logged in user.
I need to be able to remotely any one of those scripts individually.

if I am local I can run

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq "cmd"
} | ft name, MainWindowTitle
```

and this will at least give me a description of what that `CMD.exe` is doing.

But if I use any method to run this remotely (PSSession or CIMSession) MainWindowTitle will not be returned. It will always be blank.

Can anyone suggest any other methods of finding out what script is being run remotely via PowerShell.

Comment: All remote code do NOT have a user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Ses = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred
$Process = Get-CimInstance CIM_Process -CimSession $Ses | Where-Object{ $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name }

FOREACH ($Proc IN $Process) {Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $Proc -MethodName Terminate}
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Nas' helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863411/45375):

**Querying the process' *command line* is your best option**, because **GUI-related properties such as `MainWindowTitle` are fundamentally unavailable during remoting**.

However, **whether the command line allows you to identify the running script (batch file) depends on how that script was originally launched**:

- If the script was launched from an interactive console window that was first opened separately, you'll see only `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"` as the command line, and not the script's path.
- If the script was launched from File Explorer or other GUI method or via an API call, you *will* see the script file path in the command line, e.g.,
  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\jdoe\someScript.cmd" "`

  - Even that, however, is not necessarily the script that may *currently* be running if, say, the startup script invoked another script later.

By contrast, **if your scripts launch *external executables*** that do the actual work, your best bet is **query such executable processes *directly***; e.g., if your script launches `foo.exe`, use:

```
(Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $comp -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'foo.exe'").CommandLine
```

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Oops! Indeed I do - thank you; answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName . -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'cmd.exe'" -Property Name,CommandLine | ft Name,CommandLine
```